# Find a convex function $f$ which satisfies $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=a$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\Big[x\Big(f'(x)-a\Big)\Big]\neq0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

**Question 1.**

Find a function  which satisfies the following conditions:

> $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} ,\quad f\  \cup$
>
> $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=a$
>
> $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\Big[x\Big(f'(x)-a\Big)\Big]\neq0$

It relates to this  [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909803/conjecture-locus-of-a-point-with-two-tangents-to-a-convex-function).
I'm unable to find a such function.

Thanks in advance.

***Edit***: One final question (Perhaps what I should have asked).

**Question 2.**

Find a function $g$ such that:

> $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, \  g \  \cup $
>
> $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\Big[g(x)-ax \Big]=\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\quad$
>
> $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\Big[x\Big(g'(x)-a\Big)\Big]\neq0$

Let's note that if $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\Big[g(x)-ax \Big]=\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ $\ $then $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g'(x)=a$

Also it can be shown that $\exists\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}x\Big(g'(x)-a \Big) $

**Second Edit** (***(Question 2. is impossible***)

set $\lambda = k+c, c\neq 0$
then

$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\Big[g(x)-ax-k \Big]=c\neq 0\quad$

So,  $c=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\Big[g(x)-ax-k\Big]=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\Big[{x(g(x)-ax-k)\over x} \Big]\overset{{\infty}\over \infty}{=}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\Big[{\Big(x(g(x)-ax-k)\Big) '\over \Big(x\Big) '} \Big]=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\Big[g(x)-ax-k+x(g'(x)-a) \Big]=c + \lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}x\Big(g'(x)-a \Big)\\ \Longrightarrow \lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}x\Big(g'(x)-a \Big)=0$

Comment: What does $f \cup$ mean in this context?

Comment: It means that $f$ is convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not the most au fait with convex analysis but here is a function which I believe satisfies your conditions.

Consider the continuously differentiable function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x-\log(x+1) & x >0 \\ 0 &x\leq 0\end{cases}$$

whose derivative

$$f'(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x}{x+1} & x >0 \\ 0 &x\leq 0\end{cases} $$

is monotone increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ and hence $f(x)$ is convex.

Moreover, $f'(x)\to 1$ as $x\to +\infty$ and

$$x(f'(x)-1) = -\frac{x}{x+1} \to -1$$

as $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your function is only convex for $x\geq 0$ (because a convex function's derivation must be strictly increasing) but with a little adjustment it works. I would truly appreciate it, if you could also solve the question I just added.

Comment: @JohnKall I'll have a think about the new question.

Comment: It will probably be more difficult. I should have ticked your answer, because it initially answered my question, but then I realized that I asked the wrong one... Give it a try and we'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

We can make the limit anything we want. Consider
$$
x(f'(x)-a)=b\tag1
$$
Solving $(1)$ gives
$$
f(x)=ax+b\log(x)+c\tag2
$$
To make $f''(x)\ge0$, we need $-\frac{b}{x^2}\ge0$. That is, set $b\lt0$ in $(2)$.

If you want this to be defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then use
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
ax+b\log(x)+c&\text{if }x\ge1\\
c-b+(a+b)x&\text{if }x\lt1
\end{array}\right.\tag3
$$